# How do I change file system in recovery mode to read-write mode?

Tags: mount, filesystem

I have messed up my `sudoers` file and I want to change the permission on it.

When I login in recovery mode, I cannot run the command `chmod` as it is read-only option.

I tried `mount -o remount,rw /` in recovery mode. Didn't work for me:

```
Err : Ext4-fs remount. Opts errors=remount-ro
```

How can I boot into recovery mode and with read-write option?

Answer (score 197):

I did some web searching on "Recover Mode Read Only" and came across [this post on LinuxQuestions.org website](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cannot-edit-fstab-in-recovery-mode-filesystem-is-read-only-540195/).

1. Shutdown the computer
2. Boot into Recovery Mode --After BIOS load, hold down Shift key to
   access the grub menu --Once in grub menu, select the entry ending in
   "(recovery mode)"
3. From the next menu selected option to enter Root Session
4. At the root session, execute command `mount -o rw,remount /` to
   remount the filesystem as read-write

Comment: I get: "mount: special device remount does not exist"

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari You'll get that message if you added a space after "rw" in the command (ask me how I know :) ). 

It's as-written: mount(space)-o(space)rw,remount(space)/

Comment: @8bitartist Lol, true. Why is it like this?

Answer (score 21):

Since the answer is a bit old and did not work for me, I share with you my solution. I mistyped an option in `fstab` for the `/` directory (very bad, I know).

In order to mount in recovery mode with read write option the mentioned solutions did not work for me.

I simply chose the kernel with recovery mode option and pressed `e` to modify the boot parameter from `ro` to `rw`.

Comment: +1 for an alternate solution, even if it might not be ideal in many cases.

Comment: Your answer is gold!

Comment: Finaly... Best solution

Answer (score 19):

**I always use following way to change into read/write mode**

- Login in Safe Mode
- From the Menu just go to **Grub** option, it will give a message like **Updating grub will mount your system in read/write mode**. Just chose **yes** to mount your system in read/write mode. It will update your grub and will exit from **Grub** menu.
- Finally login as **root**, your system will be in read/write mode.
- You can also chose **dpkg** option from the menu to change file system to read/write mode.

It always worked for me. It helps when you don't remember the command to change into read/write mode.

Just give it a try..

Comment: what does "login in safe mode" mean?

Comment: @gman: Safe Mode is kind of login without the GUI part! You can do so by holding **Shift** while your system restarts. You'll get a **GRUB** menu from where you can choose to login in **SAFE MODE**

Comment: @gman recovery mode