# How to change "read-only" file at root prompt

Tags: read-only

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change file system in Ubuntu11.10 recovery mode to read-write mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-ubuntu11-10-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode)

After blank screen, need to change some settings in xorg.conf

Logged in at root prompt through recovery mode.

Unable to change file read-only message.

How to change the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You must first mount the drive as read/write using the Recovery Menu option, then drop to the root shell (with networking if needed).

Everything should work then.

For Ubuntu 14.04 and higher, there is no option for read/write. Instead, enable-networking option will mount the system in read/write mode.

Comment: Thanks. A newbie here. How do you mount the drive as read/write?

Comment: There's an option in the Recovery Menu.

Comment: I did some web searching on "Recover Mode Read Only" and came across the following post: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cannot-edit-fstab-in-recovery-mode-filesystem-is-read-only-540195/.

Shutdown the computer
Boot into Recovery Mode --After BIOS load, hold down Shift key to access the grub menu --Once in grub menu, select the entry ending in "(recovery mode)"
From the next menu selected option to enter Root Session
At the root session, execute command mount -o remount,rw / to remount the filesystem as read-write

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-ubuntu11-10-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode