# Change file system state in recovery mode

Tags: grub2, graphics, reboot

Sorry for the format, but im trying to do this on my smartphone since my ubuntu is down lol. I am trying to run the command `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current` in the root shell prompt but I am getting a few errors since I'm not in write mode. How do I fix this? My computer keeps booting to a blank screen right before asking for my login after I recently tried updating my nivida drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change file system in recovery mode to read-write mode?](http://askubuntu.com/q/117950/221281)

Comment: You're very right, if I only I could have search better in a full screen.. problem is fixed now.