# Sudo command not found (su login not working)

Tags: sudo, su

I had a system crash and now my Ubuntu runs into low-graphics mode. All the fixes require running commands with `sudo`. When I try this I get `sudo: command not found`. When I try logging in with `su -` I get an error: `Authentication failed`. I also tried  `sudo -i` but that did nothing.  I am really stuck here. What can I do?

Relevant info:

```
$ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 121144 Feb 28 2013 /usr/bin/sudo

-a sudo output : -bash: -a command not found
which - a sudo output: 
/usr/bin/sudo echo foo output: Permission denied
```

Comment: Exactly what is the command you try to run with sudo and what is the error reported exactly.

Comment: THe error is "Command not found", It doesnt matter what I run. Nothing works

Comment: if you try sudo -i does it work ?

Comment: First one: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin

Second one: -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 121144 Feb 28 2013 /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: sudo -i does nothing

Comment: -bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: Okay, I have no clue. Try running sudo with the full path `/usr/bin/sudo YOUR_COMMAND`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `type -a sudo` and `which -a sudo`. Then, try running `/usr/bin/sudo echo foo` and tell us if it worked.

Comment: Done I have updated the question

Comment: You need to run `type -a sudo`, `type` is a command. Also, make sure there is no space between `-` and `a`, it should be `-a`. It is much easier for us to read if you just copy/paste the command and the output directly from the terminal. The `permission denied` is interesting. Please add the output of `ls -l /usr | grep bin` and `ls -l / | grep usr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only possibility left it that one of the directories leading to `sudo` doesn't have the other executable bit set, so although the directory is in your path, `bash` can't find the binaries inside. When you try with full path, then of course you get the permission denied message. This problem with the directories is likely also the cause of your original problem with the *low-graphics mode* thing.

So please try

```
ls -ld /usr
ls -ld /usr/bin
```

both of these should report:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

permissions. If not, then it is your problem and you should set those permissions for those folders, and likely for some other folders also. But you can't do it from your installation, because you don't have access to sudo. So either boot into recovery mode or use a live CD to correct the errors. (Which were likely caused by a wrong `chmod` command.)

Comment: The permissions output is not correct. But trying to change under shell prompt (recovery mode) gives me an error: Read only file-system. My output is drw-rw-rw-

Comment: @Jacob Thats normal. You need to remount `/` read/write, look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/117950/221281)

Comment: Following that instructions and mounting the low graphics error was gone