# Cannot login with GUI nor with terminal

Tags: nvidia, login, tty

Because of two issues i am not able to login on my ubuntu system. After submitting the credentials on the login GUI I get redirected back to it.

1. something got broken on nvidia config. i just want to restore my old xorg. I cannot access any terminal. i ve tried the "text" kernel param but it does not work.
2. moreover any tty is blank screen i think because of a resolution problem of my hidpi laptop display. I ve tried also booting in recovery mode. I can just get into a read only system.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?
ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve adding the "text" kernel param on the Grub entry with "upstart". That would boot with a console. Then checking the logs (~/.xsession-errors.log) I could see .Xresources and .xprofile files had some invalid content. After cleaning those files I was able to login again.

TTYs are still blank though. But that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

About the second part: You have to [remount the filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode), `mount -o remount,rw /`.
Then you should be able to fix the problem. If you need further help post some logs, they should help finding out the problem.