# Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop with additional monitor issue

Tags: 14.04, login, multiple-monitors, lightdm

I appear to be having a relatively common login loop error as described here [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1). In brief, after an login attempt, the screen blacks out for about 5 seconds, and returns to the login screen

I am aware there are a variety of solutions to this problem, which are often resolved with editing the `.Xauthority` file. However, all of these solutions start with logging into the shell e.g. Ctrl + Alt + F3. When I attempt to log in to the shell, the monitor immediately goes idle. If I cycle through using Alt + ->, I can return to the normal login screen after a couple of goes.

I suspect the shell login screen is for whatever reason being output to a different non-existent screen. I am using a macmini 2011 with VGA output. Can anyone offer any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the mac mini uses an ATI graphics so you are probably using fglrx, if you updated the Hardware Enablement Stack it is incompatible with fglrx and it is recommended to use amdgpu (good luck with that, I've been unsuccessful, so if anyone has any good guides I'd like to hear) so you have 2 choices go into your terminal with `ctrl+alt+F1` and enter command `sudo apt-get remove fglrx*` this will reset you to basic radeon drivers which quite frankly suck.

Or you can uninstall the current image which will revert to the last version you used, `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-*`, but now you won't get security updates.

I've chosen the second option, and I feel really sketchy about it, but I can't get option 1 to even function to a satisfactory level.

Comment: So the main problem is that I can't actually get into my terminal from the login screen. `ctrl+alt+F1` just leads to my monitor becoming idle. I.e. no visual output

Comment: you can still get terminal access with recovery mode using grub, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time and mount in read-write mode http://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode

Comment: Also once you're in grub, you can just load a previous kernel and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried loading previous kernels but all freeze at `ehci-pci 0000:00:04.1: irq 22, io mem 0xd3489200`

Comment: You may not have the same issue as me, what happened that started this problem?

Comment: I think there are a number of different issues at simultaneously at play here. I can't think of a change that has particularly sparked this issue. Going to go for a full re-install of Ubuntu. An unsatisfactory solution but potentially the fastest.