# Problem during change of PATH

Tags: permissions

In my administrator account, from terminal I use the following command(mistakenly)

1. gedit ~/.pam_environment
2. PATH=/home/acer:$PATH
3. Save and close the file.
4. Restart the computer to initialize the new PATH variable.

After that, I can't open the account using earlier password. So can't install anything.

Comment: are you able to login using other account which can execute `sudo`?

Comment: No. It shows error message.

Answer (score 2):

`~/.pam_environment` isn't evaluated by a shell but by the pam_env PAM module. So you can't use shell syntax like `$PATH` there and your `$PATH` is now set to literally `/home/acer:$PATH` so programs in `/bin/`, `/usr/bin/`, ... aren't found.

Boot into recovery mode (see [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)) and edit or remove your `.pam_environment`.

Comment: I can't edit the .pam_environment during recovery mode booting? How can I do it?

Comment: See [How do I change file system in recovery mode to read-write mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode)