# Unable to write in drive

Tags: permissions, 18.04

[Drive lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEdGg.png)

I am trying to create folder in the drive with the username:zedaan . I have try to chmod the drive still the same issue `sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media/1666675566673521`

Here are the drive lists: 
[Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0uSs.png)

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). Are you trying to access `/media/zedaan/Files All in One`? Why are you issuing the command with a different path? Why do you silent (`-f`) the errors of [`chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)? We would like to see the error messages! How is the drive mounted, with which option? Please add the output of the `mount` command to your question (yes, as text, please).

Comment: @Melebius thanks for the response, basically with the drive which was write protected by some reasons. I was unable to create new folder etc. 

I have found a solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode 

Thanks for the help and I will consider your suggestions.