# Initial boot after installation works, all subsequent boots freeze on Dell Inspiron Mini

Tags: dell, freeze

So I am having a weird issue, I actually noticed it with Linux Mint, but I decided to try Ubuntu to see if the problem originated there, and it does seem to. I have a little Dell Inspiron Mini 1012. Ubuntu 15.04 and older will install and works great. The trouble starts when I try to install 15.10 or 16.04. The installer boots fine, and I am able to install. I remove the USB drive I used and reboot. The system will fully reboot into the desktop, I am able to use the system if I choose. But when I shut it down and try to start up again, the system will freeze every time. I hit escape so I can view the list of what the system is doing, and it doesn't seem to freeze on any particular thing each time, but it does freeze solid every time. No blinking cursor, no hard drive activity, nothing. After the first initial boot after installation, the system will never boot again. I am completely at a loss as for what to do, and would love to get the newer versions working on this system. If anyone needs more info, just let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Shutdown the computer
2. Boot into Recovery Mode --After BIOS load, hold down Shift key to
   access the grub menu --Once in grub menu, select the entry ending in
   "(recovery mode)"
3. From the next menu selected option to enter Root Session
4. At the root session, execute command `mount -o rw,remount /` to
   remount the filesystem as read-write
5. Execute `sudo systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds\:dell\:\:kbd_backlight.service`

Sources:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332063&p=13525821#post13525821
- https://askubuntu.com/a/117954/42551