# Stuck in emergency mod, I tried something to get out, it get worse

Tags: boot, fstab, recovery-mode, etc, uuid

edit : Sorry if I wasn't clear, I will try my best to be understable

I'm STUCK in emergency mod and I did something stupid to solve my issue
I edit the wrong UUID via

```
edit/etc/fstab
```

: I erased the 1st UUID ( 76aa9012-308b-44af-aebe-df5483c08634)

by the one from the swap file (283A159A3A15665A)

I did that because I saw an other post and I misunderstood the solution.

[more details here](https://imgur.com/gallery/wncgnAk)

Then I did as you guys told me in the comments, I went to recovery mod, I have enabled the " write" option ( see here -> https://imgur.com/PEePgKj)
Then I went to boot, I wrote

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

and then this screen appeared ( -> see here https://imgur.com/YFciJUJ )

so naturally I tried to erase my previous mistake by changing the UUID that I previously changed by the former one ( -> see here https://imgur.com/VXxMJAS)
I also tried to add a

```
#
```

before the swap UUID as I saw on an other post that it could solve my issue.

However, despite the fact that I enabled the write option, I can't save any changes ( -> see here https://imgur.com/Kizhu0G)

Moreover I have to write very quicly on this screen because if I take too much time, all of my changes are erased anyway and I go back to the recovery main page without doing anything.

My questions are : How can I save my changes and is it the best way to finnaly boot Ubuntu ?

Comment: What happens when you type `nano /etc/fstab` in recovery mode?

Comment: I'm supposed to edit your question, but I don't even understand what you did. In which file did you erase the UUID? What did you hope to achieve? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1239537/edit) your question and add the necessary infos.

Comment: I went to /etc/fstab and I tried to change my first UUID with the one written as my swap UUID.

Comment: Julien, it's really not clear what your problem is. You can use `mount -o rw,remount /` in recovery mode, to deactivate the read-only mode. Further info here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode
Hope that helps.

Comment: Béné, I did desactivate the read only mode ( see the screenschot on my post ) however  it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Julien, thanks for making the question a bit clearer. So I understand you removed the UUID of your root partition in /etc/fstab and are having trouble adding it back in revcovery mode.

There seems to be a problem with your recovery mode as you don't seem to have write acces and for some reason are being kicked out after a while - both of these things *shouldn't* happen.

Therefore I'd advise you to boot off a Ubuntu USB drive. Mount the root partition of your install using Gnome Disks. (<kbd>Super</kbd> and typing `disks` should pull up the right app.) In Gnome Disks you can also find out the UUID of the partition. Then edit fstab accordingly.

Note that the fstab file you need to edit won't be at `/etc/fstab` in the live Ubuntu session. Instead you'll find it on the partion you installed Ubuntu to, so somewhere at `/media/ubuntu/<UUID of your partition>/etc/fstab`.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried what you just told me. Unfortunely it didn't help, my recovery mod is still buggy as ever and I still got disconected after a couple of minute. At this point, as a novice, It seems to hard for me to recover my mistakes and I just want to format my SSD to redo a clean install of Ubuntu again. However, when I plug my SSD on a working pc and I tried to format it, It refuses to do so. Please can you help me ton redo a clean install of Ubuntu on this SSD ?

Comment: That's a good idea! You don't need to format the drive though. Just leave the SSD in your original system and use a Ubuntu USB drive to boot it. Then install Ubuntu and choose the SSD as installation drive. The installer will format the drive automatically.